# I'm trying to develop a WP8.1 mobile app and can't figure out how to navigate between pages in different folder

Tags: windows-8.1

I get the following error The name 'NavigationService' does not exist in the current context. I have two pages and I want to navigate between them. One page is in a different folder.

//Does'nt work the following way as the page "SecondPage" is in other folder.

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage));
```

//so...tried the below code

```
 this.Frame.Navigate(new Uri("/PageNavigation/SecondPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

But this does'nt seem to work in windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution by just typing in the whole path like this...

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Tiling.PageNavigation.SecondPage));
```

> where, **Tiling** is my Project name, **PageNavigation** is my folder name in
>   which "SecondPage" exists, **SecondPage** is my Page name which I want to
>   Navigate to..